# VueJS mounted function has effect throughout the app and not just on a required Route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an app on VueJS. I am turning on my browser camera and microphone when I got to a route /golive , when I go back to my main page I see that my camera and microphone remain on.

I am added the functions to turn media on in my mounted() function, Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Does /golive and the "main page" share the same mounted?

Comment: Did you disable the camera and microphone on unmount/destroy ?